# Breaking an XML string into three floats

Tags: python, xml, delimited

I'm parsing XML data that contains string values, space delimited, that represent floating point values:

```
<Pnts>
  <P> 123.456 987.654 867.5309</P>
  <P> 345.766 234.132 654.4564</P>
  ...
```

For each of the P items I need to assign the three float values to three variables. Currently I'm doing this:

```
for p in pnts:
    x, y, z = p.split(' ')

    x = float(x)
    y = float(y)
    z = float(z)
```

Is there a more direct (elegant) way to assign the three float variables without first setting them to strings and then re-defining them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension or generator expression:

```
x,y,z = [float(f) for f in p.split()]
```

or

```
x,y,z = (float(f) for f in p.split())
```

Or you could convert all of the data in fell swoop:

```
data = [[float(f) for f in p.split()] for p in pnts]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
for p in pnts:
    x, y, z = map(float, p.split(' '))
```